# How to print out results in NQueens

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA. Below is my code of NQueens problem. The results are [[Ljava.lang.String;@123a439b, [Ljava.lang.String;@7de26db8].

Can anyone please help? Thank you very much!  I copyied the code from other's blog. The code should be correct. I just don't know how to print out the results. I think this should be not very hard. My background is not computer science, that's maybe why I have the trouble. Thank you!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Solution {
public ArrayList<String[]> solveNQueens(int n) {
    ArrayList<String[]> res = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    if(n<=0)
        return res;

    int [] columnVal = new int[n];

    DFS_helper(n,res,0,columnVal);

    return res;
}

public void DFS_helper(int nQueens, ArrayList<String[]> res, int row, int[] columnVal){
    if(row == nQueens){
        String[] unit = new String[nQueens];
        for(int i = 0; i < nQueens; i++){
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            for(int j = 0; j < nQueens; j++){
                if(j == columnVal[i])
                    s.append("Q ");
                else
                    s.append("+ ");
            }

            unit[i] = s.toString();
            //System.out.println(unit[i]);

        }

        //System.out.println();

        res.add(unit);

      // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
       //return;
    }

    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < nQueens; i++){
            columnVal[row] = i;//(row,columnVal[row)==>(row,i)

            if(isValid(row,columnVal))
                DFS_helper(nQueens, res, row+1, columnVal);
        }
    }
}

public boolean isValid(int row, int [] columnVal){
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        if(columnVal[row] == columnVal[i]
           ||Math.abs(columnVal[row]-columnVal[i]) == row-i)
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution su = new Solution();
    int n = 4;

    System.out.println(su.solveNQueens(n));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you do `System.out.println(su.solveNQueens(n));` it prints list contents which are array and it just prints array object, but not it's contents. so, to print `array` contents you need to iterate through them.

```
Arrays.toString Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])

get result into a `list` and then print it:

```
List<String[]> res = su.solveNQueens(n);
for(String strs[] : res) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs));
}
```

You can do like this too as the above prints with `,`. Here iterating through the list and then array.

```
List<String[]> res = su.solveNQueens(n);
for(String strs[] : res) {
        for(String s: strs) {
            System.out.print(s+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

in java 8, you can make use of `stream` and `lambda`:

```
ArrayList<String[]> result = su.solveNQueens(n)
result.stream().forEach(i->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i)));
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Can you please explain more? I am new to java. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much!

Comment: You explanation helps me a lot! Thank you very very much! ^_^